# Expanded Hierarchical Tree View in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

We have a hierarchical tree view like in the picture. How to make all of the parents expanded when opened? They are collapsed and we need to expand each of them one-by-one. How can we keep them expanded?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not known way to do that, you will need to do it with a custom development